# Laravel artisan exception details

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.4, artisan-migrate

When I run artisan command, I get no error details, no stack and line numbers.
is this normal?
How can I know where is the error coming from?
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run:

```
 php artisan migrate --seed -vvv
```

to get more details.

You can also verify error log for details (by default `storage/logs/laravel.log`).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Also delete files in `bootstrap/cache` directory.

If this does not help, may be search for `AssignmentStatus` in your project to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's been catched by laravel.
You can dump the detail in the "handle" function in this file

/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php

```
public function handle($input, $output = null)
{
    try {
        $this->bootstrap();

        return $this->getArtisan()->run($input, $output);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);die;
        $this->reportException($e);

        $this->renderException($output, $e);

        return 1;
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        $e = new FatalThrowableError($e);

        $this->reportException($e);

        $this->renderException($output, $e);

        return 1;
    }
}
```